# Can I Display Date Time as saved in database without DST adjustment in View

Tags: views

My view has data from a Feed that already has the correct time stored.
Apparently the view is adjusting for DST before displaying to the user.  Thus, my Sales and Service Techs are seeing the incorrect time.
[image: Apptdate]

Comment: I would write this as an answer, but I think this is a problem with your Feeds import and not the Views formatter.  If you look at the raw data in the database, is it correct?  I suspect you have a bad timezone translation or a double timezone translation going on during the import.  I think you may need a tamper.

Comment: Fortunately I have 11 months of using the same feeds and views.  This began when Ohio changed to Daylight savings time. I will look deeper

Comment: From that screenshot, I am assuming that is Drupal 7 + Date module.  IIRC the D7 Date module stores both the UTC offset and the IANA timezone name with each value.  I highly suspect that there is a mismatch here, and potentially system/server zone misconfiguration, resulting in the timezone rules for DST not being applied properly.  Unfortunately, a bunch of wrong things can add up to the date being displayed properly until a DST switch.

Comment: D8 using most recent feeds, using composer for installation.  I changed the timezone to Halifax and it's ok until Spring.